# zip file downloaded: is it enough to remove it to be secured?

Tags: file-access, zip

I downloaded a zip file, with vb files inside. If by any chance, it contains a virus, or a source code to have access to my computer, what should I do? I removed the zip file and the folder extracted, empty the trash, and reboot my computer. I have seen once that one can enter a computer just by downloading a file, is that still true if the file has been removed? I have got Little Snitch on Mac to check if a communication is made with the outside.

Comment: Unless you ran the files within the zip file then you were not infected.  Furthermore VB files on OS X cannot be ran.  Visual Basic is a Windows only programming language.

Comment: @Ramhound, that's generally true, but there have been exceptions. File previewers and the indexing service have been compromised before, causing an infection simply by storing the file. He's probably still OK, though.

Comment: @JohnDeters the files in question Could Not run on OS X even if they wanted too

Comment: if you only download or  never unzip  the folder or run any file then its ok you can delete that  its enough to remove that  zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you download files you must be sure that you've turned autorun off, because some batch files or vb files or the java prompts asks your permission to allow the programme to run and they are always with fake prompt like some security issue for your computer. And one more thing you should be aware of is, you can check the directly connected network to your system and if any IP of different network is there it means someone else you don't want connected to your system and hence can send payloads to your system.
After getting known to the malicious activity in network you just can restart your system or delete the files which you've downloaded or end the services which may turned on due to that files.
Or better you can take help of a strong firewall security.

Comment: thanks, so as long as I delete the files, (I did not open a program though, just the zip file which contains vb files), is there still a way that something was already sent to another computer (like ip, etc.) that can allow to enter in my computer (even if the files are deleted)? So without the files in my computer and after I switch off the computer: can one still enter in my computer? Just to be sure Thanks

Comment: this is fine as long as autorun is turned off, but in the case autorun is not turned off how do you know what the malicious code may have done/installed on ur system. The only way to know is by running a full system scan to ensure that nothing else exists.

Comment: "_I have got Little Snitch on Mac to check if a communication is made with the outside._"

If this is on your mac, AutoRun and VB Files are no longer an issue. That's not saying that the infection from the zip file isn't possible, but it's highly unlikely.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I don't know what autorun is, is it turned off by default? Anyway I am a bit more relieved with the answers, thanks